# Prohibition of current item changing in QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

How I can prohibit changing current item in `QTreeWidget` (under certain conditions).

The problem is that the signal `QTreeWidget::currentItemChanged` triggered after the changing.

P.S. I tried to override `QTreeView::currentChanged` and do nothing in it, but it also did not lead to the desired result.

Comment: If the only problem is the signal, you can use `QObject::blockSignals` to temporarily disable signal sending.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the problem is not emitting a signal, but the widget behavior.

Comment: Try to subclass `QItemSelectionModel`, reimplement its `setCurrentIndex` method to do nothing when needed, and use the selection model with `QTreeWidget::setSelectionModel`.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help. I think this is due to the fact that I can not override `QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex`, because it is not a virtual.

Comment: You're overriding it in the wrong class. `QItemSelectionModel::setCurrentIndex` is virtual.

Comment: Excuse my inattention. I tried to do it. In `MyTreeWidgetItem::MyTreeWidgetItem(...)` coded `QTreeWidget::setSelectionModel( new MySelectionModel( QTreeWidget::model(), this ) );`, where in `MySelectionModel` reimplement `setCurrentIndex` (empty).  So, items in tree still switched. Disappeared only emitting `QTreeWidget::currentItemChanged`, but it disappeared even without reimplementing `setCurrentIndex`. I think, it requires some signal connecting. But it's secondarily.

Comment: Maybe disabling the whole widget with `setEnabled(false)` is acceptable?

Comment: The problem is that in currentItemChanged connected method there is a condition that when this is True we wan't to call something like preventDefault(). The blockSignal method isn't usefull in this case because the signal is allready emitted. We want to call setCurrentItem to go back, but don't call again the connected method. After the execution of connected method **then** the selection of QTreeWidget is changed. We have to prevent it (prohibitted). The only clear solution is to subclass the QTreeWidget and use it in the abstract method, the re-define what method-events?

Comment: Anyway, one simple solution is to use a singleShot QTimer, there you can blockSignals the setDesiredItem and then blockSignal(False) to be ok.